# creating more testable code while avoiding static/non-static field initializer issues

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nunit, moq

I'm passing a non static string into MessageQueue:

```
public virtual MessageQueue MessageQueue { get; } = new MessageQueue(ConfigHelper.QLocation);
```

**QLocation** is non-static; however, **MessageQueue** requires a static parameter.

I am getting this exception:

> Cannot access a non-static field in static context

My **ConfigHelper** class is a wrapper for my configuration file values. I can make the ConfigHelper class static; however, that would make testing much more difficult.

**Is there a way to handle this issue, while still maintaining code testability?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use `QLocation` in a static way(`ConfigHelper.QLocation`) while it is a non-static filed(as you wrote...)

Try this:

```
.... = new MessageQueue(new ConfigHelper().QLocation);
```

It'll remove the error.

IMO, you should inject `MessageQueue` via this CUT(class under test) C'tor. Your class has a dependency to `MessageQueue`. 
If you don't want to inject a `MessageQueue` I offer you to inject the connection string instead of the configuration.

Comment: Thanks! Wondering why I can't do this inside the class with the c# 6.0 syntax  just like in the question?

Comment: Also why are the parentheses necessary after confighelper

Comment: The problem is not with the C# 6 syntax. The problem is this; You are trying to call a non static method(property is a syntactic sugar for writing a getter method) using the syntax of static method. In the following snippet `new ConfigHelper().QLocation` I create a new instance of  `ConfigHelper` then I call the instance property `QLocation`. I use parentheses with the `new` keyword to call the class C'tor.

Comment: thank you very much for the thorough explanation!! is there a performance hit for using the syntactic sugar the way you are recommending vs. initializing within the constructor?